# Check if min-width is set

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm creating a responsive layout using [Tachyons](https://tachyons.io/) media queries:

```
render() {
  const { UI } = this.props.state

  const containerStyle = {
    //right: `${UI.isMenuOpened ? 0 : `calc(-16rem + 4rem)`}`, // if min-width is setted
    right: `${UI.isMenuOpened ? 0 : `calc(-40% + 4rem)`}`, // if min-width is not setted
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="bg-gray w-40 min-w5 h-100 absolute o-50 flex transition"
      style={containerStyle}
    >
     //...
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see I want that the width of the div changes: `40%` and `min-width = w5` (`16rem`).
The problem is that I don't know how to change the `right` value in `containerStyle`. 
In `calc(A + B)` the is A that represents the width of the div and B that represents the padding (always `4rem`). 
What I need is to change A: it would be `40%` is `min-width` is not set, and `w5` if `min-width` is set.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the default value for `min-width` is `0`, just check against that with Boolean type coercion (`0 == false`):

```
right: `${UI.isMenuOpened ? 0 : `calc(${elem.style.minWidth ? "-40%" : "w5"} + 4rem)`}`
```